# Image  chart-google 

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to get a radar chart from google api similar to below .I could get everything except the equally distributed 0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3

[image: Sampleradar]

In my chart currently it takes min value out of the data given and max value ,and divisions between .its so if 6 is my max value and min value is 3. at very centre of circle it is 3 and then next cud be 3.4,and last extreme edge is 6.What change should i make in below code.to get a distribution ( say 0 to 6) evenly.

```
         function drawVisualization() {
      var options = {};
      // Chart API chart type 'rs' is radar chart
      options.cht = 'r';
      // set the line colors
      options.colors = ['#00FF00'];

      // fill the area under the lines
      //options.fill = true;

      // create a grid for the chart
     // options.chg = '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0';
      //  options.chxl: '0:|1|2|3|4|5|6';
var arr = [["165q",1.3333333333333],["160q",6],["161q",6.6666666666667],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]];
      //var pi = '\u03C0';

      dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr, true);
      // Treat first row as data as well.

      var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `axis-range: chxr` parameter with the `custom axis labels: chxl` parameter:

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#axis_range

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params#axis_labels